# Routing Power vs. Power plane (high frequency)

Tags: power-supply, power, decoupling-capacitor, routing

As a beginner, I'm curious about handling fast analog signals with nanosecond rise times.

Do the decoupling capacitors of ICs need to recharge rapidly to supply charge effectively?

Would employing a dedicated power plane next to a ground plane offer better performance due to lower impedance in this case?

Alternatively, is routing power acceptable? What factors should I consider, and can anyone recommend helpful sources for further reading?

I've come across information suggesting that without any compelling reason, routing power is as good as a dedicated power plane in terms of functionality. The only compelling reason I've read about is the need for very high supply currents.

Comment: Have you looked into PDN (power distribution network) analysis yet?

Comment: No, any recommendations where to start?